# How to implement full row selecting in GridView without select button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I'm implementing a feature that when the user press on any point in the row in a GridView the row will be selected instead of Select button.

[image]

To implement that, I'm using the following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Set the hand mouse cursor for the selected row.
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "this.style.cursor = 'hand';");

        // The seelctButton exists for ensuring the selection functionality
        // and bind it with the appropriate event hanlder.
        LinkButton selectButton = new LinkButton()
        {
            CommandName = "Select",
            Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text
        };

        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(selectButton);
        e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] =
             Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(selectButton, "");
    }
}
```

With the code above, there are the following problems:

- This works fine only if I `EnableEventValidation` for the page is set to `false`.
- The `SelectedIndexChanged` is only fired just in case the `Grid.DataBind()` is called in `Page_Load` for the page (in every postback).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better implementation?

---

**Edit:**
When `EnableEventValidation` is set to `true`, the following error will appear:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You must add this on every postback and not only on databinding. Therefore you should use the [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx)-Event of the GridView.

For example

(C#):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

(VB.Net):

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem of setting `EnableEventValidation` to false.

Comment: @Homam: have you used my code and you are still getting the "invalid postback/callback argument"-error? I can't reproduce this error in my project, but there might be another reason for this. I have not the time now to investigate this further. You could use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx) to avoid it. Maybe [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DoubleClickGridviewRow.aspx) helps.

Comment: What language is that to describe the style? I've tried using CSS but that doesn't seem to work. For example its not background-color, its backgroundColor.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of doing it on `RowCreated`, you could do it on `Render()`. That way you could use the overload of `GetPostBackClientHyperlink` with true on `registerForEventValidation` and avoid the "invalid postback/callback argument" error.

Something like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
      foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
      {
        if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          r.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
          r.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
          r.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
          r.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + r.RowIndex,true);

        }
      }

      base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Comment: This also solved my problem. All the other posts on the Internet are telling you to disable `EnableEventValidation` which is opening your site up to injection attacks, this only one is the true answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hiddenColumn
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .rowGrid
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" >
            <RowStyle CssClass="rowGrid" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddenColumn"
                    ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddenColumn" FooterStyle-CssClass="hiddenColumn" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr.rowGrid")
            .live("click", function (event) {
                $(this).find("input[type='button'][value='Select']").click();
            });

            $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type='button'][value='Select']")
                .live("click", function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one 
add OnSelectedIndexChanged event in grid

```
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="Grid_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

and then on code behind

```
 protected void Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvSummary.SelectedRow;
    //Int32 myvalue= Convert.ToInt32(row.Attributes["ColumnName"].ToString());
   }
```

and set EnableViewState="false"
but here u have to perform two more things that u have already done in your code means
set EnableEventValidation  to false and Grid Databinding on page Load..

Answer (score -2):

Try using `<asp:LinkButton>` around your `<tr>` in ASPX code, set the LinkButton's `CommandName='Select'` And in item command event, process this command and set the style of a selected row!

Comment: are you sure having a linikbutton between the td and the tr generates a valid fully compliant HTML ?

Comment: @Davide Piras: Standards compliant HTML was not mentioned in the question as a requirement! If that is a requirement, then don't accept the solution! I showed up some possibilities!

Comment: I disagree, I did not vote you down and won't but even if not mentioned in original post, come on we are in Summer 2011 (almost), let's give cross browser and fully compliant answers only :) ;-)

Comment: @Davide Piras: I am not bothered about down votes! I fully agree with you about standards compliance! But, I just tried to help! Nothing more nothing less! I have faced a similar situation as @Homan, but then I had to get this working on production server at the earliest. So, then couldn't afford to look for standards compliance! ;-) Thought, this guy was also in a similar situation and would benefit from what I did at that time as a quick fix. Cheers! :-)