# How do I cancel the page refresh caused by Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
r.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((Control)this.gridView, "Select$" + r.RowIndex);
```

Hi, I use the above code to catch a click event on a row in a GridView in Asp.net.. This code works and I'm able to catch the newly selected row in OnSelectdIndexChanged, but the postback also causes a full page refresh.

Is there any way to cancel the page refresh but still change the selected row without adding the 'select' button?

Comment: What do you want to do with the "newly selected row"? If you need something done in code behind you will need a postback. If so you could use an [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx). If you need to do something in front end only you should take another approach.

Comment: I simply need to know which index was clicked so I can go to a detail page of the selected item, if the page refreshes it does a couple api calls which slow down the speed of the site, I will have a look at the Update panel, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `OnRowDataBound` event to add attributes to the GridView.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //add the current row number
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("rowNumber", e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());

            //add an item from the database
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("itemID", DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "database_id").ToString());

            //or add a click directy and redirect with javascript
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.href='/newPage.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "database_id").ToString() + "'");
        }
    }
```

If you are not using the 3rd attribute in my snippet you need to handle the row click clientside. You can do that with jQuery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr").click(function () {
                var rowNumber = $(this).attr("rowNumber");
                var itemID = $(this).attr("itemID");
                alert("This is row number: " + rowNumber + ". It has ID: " + itemID);
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need the RowCreated event in the GridView to do so. See the sample below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

You can see this link for more on selecting rows without select button - [How to implement full row selecting in GridView without select button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250545/how-to-implement-full-row-selecting-in-gridview-without-select-button)

To prevent the PostBack, I would recommend to use UpdatePanel that I commented earlier and then deleted. Here is a sample to put the GridView inside UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID=" ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID=" UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           </asp:GridView>
      </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It's a bit of code. So I am sharing a link in the comment section. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is what I'm doing. The post back causes the page to refresh, but I want to cancel that refresh, or just make sure it doesn't happen somehow

Comment: Never mind for the late reply. I was thinking of UpdatePanel. Please see this link - http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/08/select-gridview-row-onclick-of-cell-javascript.html?m=1 Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll have a look at the Update panel!

Comment: Hi, I implemented the UpdatePanel with ContentTemplate, but it still refreshes the current page, which executes my api calls again...