# Error when binding gridview on page load

Tags: c#, gridview, templatefield

I was using button click event to bind the data into gridview and used templatefield to modify one of the column to make it clickable but when I bind the gridview on a page load, it shows the data and I can click the data that needs to be clicked but the problem occurs when I click the data. It says this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I don't know what is happening here because it was working fine when using a button to trigger the gridview

Comment: You have to show your code, otherwise we can't fix it. But you should register client side events on your `GridViewRow.Cell` with `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink` in `RowCreated` of the `GridView`.

Comment: How do i register it with Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink?

Comment: Edit your question, include your code, then we can help to fix it. However, i've provided an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6250846/284240

Comment: Please look at my edited version showing the code.

Comment: well, you haven't shown the code where you register the client script

Comment: You mean the gridview template code?

Comment: Yes _" used templatefield to modify one of the column to make it clickable"_ Also, your `getData` is incomplete, isn't it? You return a `DataTable` which you haven't initialized.

Comment: No, there is more code which initializes the class that holds this data table and the getdata is completed with more data if it is not a "Event" and that works fine. But right now I am looking at making the Event gridview work that shows all the events and makes the StadiumName clickable. Let me update this with templatefield that i use

Comment: Please check the updated version

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now. I simply had to create a new method called BindGridview() then use if (!IsPostBack) to call that method and it works fine now :D