# Grid View content click and selection

Tags: asp.net

I have made a `GridView` and enabled the `selection` property to it. Now `select` comes next to every row in the gridview. I want to remove the `select text/tag` and selection should be done on the click on the content.
How can i do this?
:)

Comment: also try to elaborate as what language you wanna try into

Comment: i hvn't tried much...language is asp.net

Comment: withour seeing what you have tried how can we help you. post whatever you have done till now relevant with this

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250545/how-to-implement-full-row-selecting-in-gridview-without-select-button and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686240/making-an-entire-row-clickable-in-a-gridview

Comment: thanks alegiecas....i guess this is what i am looking for..