# Add Row Click Event to Asp.Net GridView Rows

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Is there a way to add a RowClick Event to Gridview Rows without adding a button to each one? I want to be able to click anywhere in the row and raise the SelectedIndexChanged event.

I tried the following but I need to add pages enableEventValidation="true" and I really don't want to do that.

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Try
        Select Case e.Row.RowType
            Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex))
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The RowCommands wont work either because you have to have a button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an entire row clickable in a gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686240/making-an-entire-row-clickable-in-a-gridview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did step 1 of 2.  First part was registering the `onclick` in the `RowDataBound`.  Now you need to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  I'm not a VB.Net guy, so I'm not 100% sure on how to wire it up.  The event handler will look like this, though:

```
Private Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Do stuff here.
End Sub
```

Also, change your `onclick` wire up code to use `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` instead of `Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink`.

Here is some example markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    Width="665px"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0033CC" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You are correct, however I get error about enabling page events which could compromise security.

Comment: @tszoro, check my edit, I noticed you were using a different `Page.ClientScript` method than I was in my code.

Comment: After editing the code I get Server Error Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/>. But it does hit the page load.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't seen that.  My test application on my computer is all in C#, FWIW.

Comment: If I put EnableEventValidation="false" in my page declaration then everything works great. But that is probably not a wise move for security purpose. Do you have any other suggestions for this?

Comment: To fix the rest of it I looped the GridView rows and added gr.Attributes.Add("onclick",Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" & gr.RowIndex, True)) to each gridview row in the Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter) event and all works now. thanks

Comment: Note: As an alternative for this you can also write a __doPostBack event in Javascript and get the params and eventtarget on Postback. function GridViewPostBack(row_idx) {
            __doPostBack(row_idx, "GridView1RowClick");
        }